# Nested Lookup Functions? Need to match up two things

Tags: vb.net, report, lookup, builder

So I'm working in microsoft sql server report builder and here is essentially what I'm trying to do in code:

*(Under report variables)*

**vChargeStatusID = Lookup(Fields!CREDIT_CARD_TRANSACTION_ID.Value, Parameters!CREDIT_CARD_TRANSACTION_ID.Value, Fields!CHARGE_STATUS_ID.Value, "DataSet1")**

*(As an expression for a filter)*

**Lookup(Variables!vChargeStatusID.Value, Fields!CHARGE_STATUS_FK.Value, Fields!CONTRACT_NUMBER.Value, "DataSet1")**

I've tried using the variable and the expression for the variable to try to create another calculated field, but no luck. I keep getting the error that I can't use nested lookup functions.

**Basically what I'm trying to do is, first, find two things that are equal to each other to retrieve a number. Then I need to take that number and match it to something else to finally return the contract number.**

I cannot figure this out.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***All credit goes to my boss who figured this out!***

*Step one*: Create **another** dataset, which is *embedded*. This dataset then has a filter that takes a field, in this case it's **CREDIT_CARD_TRANSACTION_ID**, and evaluated it be true to the parameter, **pCreditCardTransactionID**. This makes sure that the second dataset is ONLY going to display to me the Contract number, which is the very last thing I needed from the Lookup Function.

*Step two*: Create an *internal* parameter that the default value is set to the field **CONTRACT_NUMBER** from the second dataset (**ContractNumberLookup**).

*Step three*: Create a filter on the table. The **CONTRACT_NUMBER** from the original dataset is set to equal the internal parameter.

Tada! 
I hope this helps. If any clarification is needed, let me know!

Answer (score 5):

So, a very simple way to accomplish this is to place a field on your report (`TextBox1.value`) that will hold your first lookup value.

For example, your first look up will return a vendor ID (`DataSet2`) from a customer order (`DataSet1`).

```
TextBox1.expression = Lookup(Fields!CustOrderID.Value,Fields!CustOrder_ID2.Value,Fields!VendorID.Value,"DataSet2")
```

But now you need to find the vendor name from a Vendor Master table (`DataSet3`).  You can do another look up to the Vendor Master table using the `ReportItems!TextBox1.value` as the first value of the look up. That way you do not get the scope issue.

```
TextBox2.expression = Lookup(ReportItems!Textbox1.value,Fields!VendorID.Value,Fields!VendorName.Value,"DataSet3")
```